# Function to return size off array always returns 2

Tags: c++, arrays, function, return

I was brushing up on my *C++* (using eclipse and cygwin) by writing functions over arrays.
I have the following code:

```
int getArraySize(int a[]){
    int size = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    return size;
}


int main(void) {
    int arr[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    string s = "size of array: ";
    cout << s << getArraySize(arr) << endl;
    cout << s << sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]) << endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I expect to get this output:

```
size of array: 5
size of array: 5
```

but instead I get this:

```
size of array: 2
size of array: 5
```

I've tried this program with other sizes of arrays, and the function `getArraySize()`
always returns 2. Anyone know what's up?

Comment: If I got a cent every time this is asked, I could buy Apple. Twice.

Comment: Just use `vector` (or `array` if you are an expert) and everything will be better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like an array declaration, but it is not:

```
int getArraySize(int a[]){
```

This is just a pointer-to-int.  Therefore `sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0])` will just give you the ratio between the size of a pointer and the size of the pointed-to thing.  The situation does not change if you put a number between the brackets, like this:

```
int getArraySize(int a[5]){
```

To the C++ compiler, that is the same as `int getArraySize(int *a)`.  C++ does not pass arrays by value.  It passes a pointer to the first element of the array.  When you give an array argument, the argument *decays to a pointer*.

The `sizeof()` operator *will* give you the total number of bytes in an array when you pass it an *actual* array variable, as in this:

```
    int arr[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    int arr_size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
```

Comment: But one should remember that sizeof is compile time. So it only works for arrays that have known compile time size. What the asker wants to do would never work.

Comment: @Jarryd:  That is a good point.  There are ways to abuse `template` that will generate specialized versions of functions based on the array length, giving the illusion that a function call gave the length, but really it's generating a specialized template function.

Comment: @Joe abuse is slightly strong; works very well when the function gets inlined out anyway.

Comment: I see, thanks for the quick reply! is there any good way to get the size of an array in a function based on what's been passed in (which is, if I understand correctly, a pointer to element 0)?

Comment: You have to pass it in as an argument.  Or, instead of using bare arrays, use `std::vector<>`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the C++ syntax here is a bit misleading.

You cannot pass an array to a C++ function, you can only pass a pointer to the first element.

In C++ the declaration

```
void foo(int x[])
```

is EXACTLY the same as

```
void foo(int *x)
```

Even if you put a size between brackets as in

```
void foo(int x[10])
```

the number `10` is not a syntax error but will be completely ignored.

You however infer an array size from a template function, using a somewhat weird syntax:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
size_t ArraySize(T (&)[N])
{
    return N;
}
```

The `sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0])` trick works only if used in a macro... it cannot be placed in a function.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking the size of `int a[]` which is really a pointer

it looks like you are on a **64 bit machine** so:

```
sizeof(64 bit pointer) = 8

sizeof (int) = 4

8/4 = 2
```

On a 32 bit machine you would get a 1

The problem is that you are not getting the size of `arr` and there really isn't a way to do that until c++11 where you can use a `std::array` instead

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that c++ passes arrays by reference hence you are simply dividing the size of addresses.

Comment: It's not that arrays are passed by reference (which would work), but that the array argument declaration decays into a pointer declaration, which is why the result is `sizeof(int*)/sizeof(int)`.

Comment: Yes apologies - that is what I meant, just poorly phrased.